# logscale in Kibana with zero values

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I'd like to show a Kibana 4 line graph of clicks on an ad over time in log scale.
sometime there are no clicks.

Is there a way to ad an "epsilon" to the values so I can enable log-scale in the options? Maybe using the "Advanced" Y-axis parameters?